# Which tense should be used in this sentence, past simple or present perfect simple?

Tags: tenses

Van Gogh has sold only one painting during his lifetime.

OR

Van Gogh sold only one painting during his lifetime.

Comment: Neither is incorrect; the unmarked (and stand-alone) version is with the past simple. The first may be used in a lively running narrative: 'Let's look at the Post-Impressionists and the world they leave behind them. They have brought about a radical shift in the approach to painting, but their efforts have not been commensurably rewarded – Van Gogh has sold only one painting during his lifetime.

Comment: Generally speaking, #1 would *not* be considered "valid", because Present Perfect doesn't really work with a subject that no longer exists. That's why ***Today has been fun*** is acceptable, but ***Yesterday has been fun*** isn't.

Comment: You also can't use present perfect when the subject is dead. So (1) is ungrammatical.